# Handle_additional_input by Repl.it

Tags: javascript, function, replit

I'm having a hard time what's wrong in my code, I got the right answer but I don't know why whenever I submit my answer it says that I have a "Handle_additional_input" error that's why I got a failed result every time.

[image: Here is my answer]

[image: Now these are the errors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's saying you need to be able to handle an object with more or less keys (not exactly 3).  Here's a way you could do it for arbitrary size:

```
function productOfValues(obj) {
  return Object.values(obj).reduce(
    (acc, val) => acc * val,
    1
  )
}
```

this is reducing the array of values - for each value, you multiply by the accumulator